# Adding a shadow to a view with rounded corners

Tags: ios, swift

This is the code for corners.

```
self.newView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
self.newView.layer.clipsToBound = true
```

Please help me with the shadow code as well

Answer (score 3):

You do add a shadow layer in a similar way:

```swift
newView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
newView.backgroundColor = .blue
newView.clipsToBounds = true

// shadow
newView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
newView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
newView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
newView.layer.shadowRadius = 10
newView.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

[image]